# Entity Framework model does not contain schema info

Tags: c#, entity-framework

C#, Visual Studio 2017, EF 6.2

I have created my database first model. I selected the tables I need in my model.

Now when I run my application and navigate to a controller which has data access, I get an exception about a table. Invalid object name. dbo.Users

Now I have added that table to my context, but the schema of the table is not dbo.

In other projects, I see a mapping file which sets out the schema for each entity, but I do not have that file for this model.

Where can I set which schema to use for entities? And why didn't EF include that as it knows the schema at the time of adding it? Also why is this happening this time? I have added many models to many projects and never encountered this.

Comment: You need to have an .edmx in your project.